# Who is Thoreau quoting (or paraphrasing) here in Walden?

Tags: allusions, walden, henry-david-thoreau

The [passage in question](https://books.google.com/books?id=UnNbAAAAMAAJ&dq=From%20an%20army%20of%20three%20divisions%20walden&pg=PA345#v=onepage&q=From%20an%20army%20of%20three%20divisions%20walden&f=false) is in *Walden*'s conclusion:

> The philosopher said "From an army of three divisions one can take
>   away its general, and put it in disorder; from the man the most abject
>   and vulgar one cannot take away his thought."

Who is Thoreau referencing here? Is it anyone in particular, or is he making more of a general reference to "The Philosopher" as a cultural construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from Confucius, in his [*Analects*, 9.26](http://www.acmuller.net/con-dao/analects.html#div-10).

> The Master said: “You can snatch away the general of a large army, but you cannot snatch away the will of even the lowliest of men.”

This connection is made in Bill McKibben's edition of *Walden*, [page 307](https://books.google.com/books?id=AZIDAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307).